# Show and count association of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, associations, relationship

I would like to count the number of users that belong to a team which belongs to a project. The associations are as follows:

```
user belongs_to :team
team has_many :users
project has_many :teams
team belongs_to :project
```

In the projects/show.html.erb, I am using the following code to count the total number of users belonging to all teams which belong to a project

```
<h2 class="number"><%= @project.teams.users.count %></h2>
```

The error I am receiving is: `undefined method 'users'`. I am also using Devise
Is a method in project_controller.rb required for this to work?

Comment: add an association `has_many :users, through: :teams` in `Project` and then use `@project.users`

Comment: @kiddorails is correct, as is Subash, but the answer here is better because it does not break the law of demeter: http://rubyblog.pro/2016/09/rails-demeters-law-and-delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, it is **not** clear what you want exactly, this is my *best guess* at the answer.

You can add a new [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association to model `Project` to get the count of all the users in a project.

```
class User
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :users
end

class Project
  has_many :teams
  has_many :users, through: :teams   # <--- New association
end

project = Project.find(<project_id>)

# Get the count of all users in a project
project.users.count

# Get the count of users in a team
team = project.teams.find(<team_id>)   # Or `Team.find(<team_id>)`
team.users.count
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `@project.teams` it will return you an array as a list of teams because a project has many teams so to find out the number of users for the first team in that project you can do

```
@project.teams.first.users.count
```

or you need to find the team you want and then do `.users.count` on that